# Reference MasterPage in HTML file instead of ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some pages written in `cshtml` but they don't use any of the `razor` features. Basically they use knockout javascript and then query MVC controller methods for `get` and `post`.

I don't want to use any WinForms features, I just want to make AJAX calls.

I want to use these pages in a WebForms project but want to know if there are any issues with just using plain `.html` files inside a WebForms project. Will this cause any major issues with the Web Forms project? Can I still reference a MasterPage?

Comment: nope you can't. asp.net has to run thru it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML files in you WebForms project as well in ASP.Net MVC project as long as you don't need any server side processing of such files...

But using master pages requires server side processing, so plain HTML files would not work for that.

As an option you can use such files in IFrame rendered by regular ASPX page or just include all content onto ASPX page (read file and write without encoding).